# NodeJS Sequelize - Cannot read property '_isSequelizeMethod' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a NodeJS server using Express.
For my database I use Sequelize, and I defined my models like on the Sequelize documentation:

models/index.js

```
"use strict";

var fs        = require("fs");
var path      = require("path");
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");

var sequelize = new Sequelize('mydb', 'root', '', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql',

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  }
});
var db        = {};

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== "index.js");
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if ("associate" in db[modelName]) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

models/server.js

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Server = sequelize.define('Server', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    reference: DataTypes.STRING,
    name: DataTypes.STRING
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
    paranoid: false,
    underscored: true,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'server'
  });

  return Server;
};
```

models/subscriber.js

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Subscriber = sequelize.define('Subscriber', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: ['email', 'phone']
    },
    contact: DataTypes.STRING,
    server_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    notified: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    last_notified: DataTypes.DATE
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
    paranoid: false,
    underscored: true,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'subscriber',
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Subscriber.belongsTo(models.Server, { foreignKey: 'server_id', targetKey: 'id' });
      }
    }
  });

  return Subscriber;
};
```

And here my route :

```
var models  = require('../models');

app.get('/subscribe/:type/:contact/:ref', function(req, res) {
        var type = req.params.type;
        var contact = req.params.contact;
        var ref = req.params.ref;

        models.Subscriber.findAll().then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        });

        res.render('full/subscribed.twig', {
            type: type,
            contact: contact,
            server : server
        });
    });
```

And when I access my route I have this error message :

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property '_isSequelizeMethod' of undefined
at /Users/me/Projects/nodejs/myproject/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1077:20
at Array.map (native)
at Object.QueryGenerator.selectQuery (/Users/me/Projects/nodejs/myproject/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1067:55)
at QueryInterface.select (/Users/me/Projects/nodejs/myproject/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-interface.js:669:25)
at null.<anonymous> (/Users/me/Projects/nodejs/myproject/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1398:32)
at tryCatcher (/Users/me/Projects/nodejs/myproject/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/me/Projects/nodejs/myproject/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:510:31)
at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/me/Projects/nodejs/myproject/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:567:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/me/Projects/nodejs/myproject/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:612:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/me/Projects/nodejs/myproject/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:691:18)
at Async._drainQueue (/Users/me/Projects/nodejs/myproject/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
at Async._drainQueues (/Users/me/Projects/nodejs/myproject/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/Users/me/Projects/nodejs/myproject/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

I tried to do some experiences on an independent NodeJS file and everything work fine, I just launch my standalone js file with some actions on database and everything is ok. By when I do the exact same things on my Express route I have this error...

Someone have an idea of why ?

Thanks in advance,
Steve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok found it :

It's because I have add some function to Object prototype...

When sequelize get the Object of options of your model if you have some custom functions on your Object prototype it fail...

On node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js (line 1067)

```
mainAttributes = mainAttributes && mainAttributes.map(function(attr) {
```

The mainAttributes contains my custom functions like that :

```
[ 'id',
  'reference',
  'name',
  [ undefined, 'join' ],
  [ undefined, 'getKeyByValue' ] ]
```

My functions I have added to Object are join and getKeyByValue.

So to conclude, don't add custom functions to Object.prototype when you use Sequelize ;)

Hope it wil help other people.

Comment: apologies but  could not understand what you are trying to communicate.. could you pls elaborate where i have to make changes to remove this error. i am facing similar issue with exact same stack trace

Comment: Hi Amritpal, in my code I had something like "Object.prototype.join = function(){};" this line was generating my error. Try to console.log node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js (line 1067) the variable "mainAttributes", you will see.

Answer (score 1):

When you import a table, it's already added to the `sequelize.models` array so you don't need to explicity added again. The sequelize docs need to be updated to the following:

```js
readdirSync(__dirname)
.filter(file => (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== 'index.js'))
.forEach(file => {
    sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file))
})

Object
.keys(sequelize.models)
.forEach(modelName => {
    if ('associate' in sequelize.models[modelName]) {
        sequelize.models[modelName].associate(sequelize.models)
    }
})
```